# Can you set your visual studio 2012 windows to be independently active?

Tags: windows, window-manager, visual-studio-2012

When using Visual Studio 2012 with multiple code windows on each monitor, I would like to be to have only one active code window.

If I am browsing a stack overflow answer in my browser and I give visual studio the focus. All visual studio windows become active and my browser window will be hidden. I would like only the selected window to become active.

This is how visual studio 2010 worked and they changed it. Is there an option or plug-in which will grant the desired functionality ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is one of the side-effects of the new window layout engine. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386063.aspx Don't know if there's a workaround.

Comment: I hope there is I keep looking for one.

Answer (score 1):

Does this fix the problem? Works for me with VS2013 and VS2015...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this reproduceable with one monitor only? I tried to reproduce it, but didn't get the bahaviour you decribed:

Setup:

- VS Main Window open with some files
- Second VS window with some other files
- all Windows not maximised

Behauviour

1. Second VS Window active, covers part of browser -> Tab to Browser -> One Tab back -> Second VS Window active, covers part of browser; VS Main stays back
2. Main VS Window active, covers part of browser -> Tab to Browser -> One Tab back -> MainVS Window active, covers part of browser; VS Second stays back

Tabbing seems to work as expected here. Perhaps this issue only applies, when you use maximised windows? Could that be a workaround?

Comment: You did this with vs 2012 ?

Comment: Yes, 11.0.60223.01 Update 2 CTP - to be exact ;)